# Join an association multiple times with different aliases

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I think, that the problem that i have is a bug in Hibernate (already tracked - https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-879 ).

My question is - Is there a workaround to join a table multiple times with a grails criteria query?

The SQL would be straight forward:

```
SELECT s FROM Store AS s   
    INNER JOIN s.Products AS prod1  
    INNER JOIN s.Products AS prod2  
WHERE 
    prod1.Type = 'Shoes'   
AND 
    prod2.Type = 'Shirts'
```

When i use "createAlias" in the grails criteria query (one for prod1 and one for prod2) i´am getting the following error:

org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: studyTags
...

One possibilty might by, to do the query with an OR (one single JOIN and WHERE prod.Type = 'Shoes' OR 'Shirts') and then filter the result set. The problem with this solution is, that if i specify a limit for the criteria query (max Results), the real result (after filtering) might have less entries than specified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: My real code, where i experienced this issue is pretty complex. To break the problem down i used this example with Store and Product... I think the query would look like

```
Store.withCriteria{
    createAlias('products', 'prod1')
    createAlias('products', 'prod2')

    and{
        eq('prod1.Type', 'Shoes')
        eq('prod2.Type', 'Shirts')
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense to me. Can you describe in words what is the result you expect.  Do you want to get all stores that sell both "Shoes" and "Shirts"

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a old question I came acroos into it when searching my solution. So I figured out there is probably a bug in hibernate that make duplikacte aliases impossible. The work around I used is using pure SQL for finding a limited "id's" list and there check if other query requrements matched the list. In this example it could be"

```
select x.id from XTable x join products prod1 on... join products prod1 on... where prod1.type= 'shoes' and prod.type = 'shirts';
```

and then check

```
select x.id from XTable x where x.id in ("result of the query")
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this - I think this will return all stores that contain both a product of type "Shoes" and "Shirts"

```
Store.withCriteria{
    createAlias('products', 'prod')

    and{
        eq('prod.Type', 'Shoes')
        eq('prod.Type', 'Shirts')
    }
}
```

Comment: Upon further investigation....  This is going to produce: inner join prod on some_field where prod.type = 'Shoes' and prod.type = 'Shirts' which will always return 0 results...